# "Echt komplex" in English?

Tags: complex-numbers, translation-request, mathematical-german

In German, we sometimes use the term "echt komplex" for complex numbers which aren't real, i.e. for complex numbers with a non-vanishing imaginary part.  Is there an English equivalent for this?  (I obviously don't mean *purely imaginary*.)

Comment: really complex :-)

Comment: Often it is just said that $z=a+bi$ is a *non-real complex number*, if $b\neq 0$. But be careful. In German, $z=a+bi$ is called "echt-complex" if **both** $a$ and $b$ are nonzero. If $a=0,b\neq 0$, then $z$ is called "rein imaginär".

Comment: For a reference and further discussion ("unecht komplex"), see for example [here](https://www.onlinemathe.de/forum/komplexe-zahlenecht-komplexe-Zahlen).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well, this "reference" is some random online forum.  I give several textbook references below that use the term in the sense I use it in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I have sometimes seen a different definition for "echt komplex".
Let $z=a+bi$ a complex number. Then we have three cases.

*Case 1:* If $a=0$, then $z$ is called "rein imaginär" (purely imaginary).

*Case 2:* If $b=0$, then $z$ is called "rein reell" (purely real).

*Case 3:* If *both* $a,b$ are nonzero, then $z$ is called "echt komplex".

Edit: There are also references, which define for a complex number $z$, that $z$ is "echt komplex" if and only if it is non-real. For this interpretation the answer to the question is then just: *$z$ is non-real"*. I have never seen  "genuinely complex", or "typically complex".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though you answered it in a comment

Comment: Where do you get this from?  A quick search gave me dozens of German text books that agree with my definition of "echt komplex" meaning "complex, but not real".  For example, Heuser: "Lehrbuch der Analysis - Teil 1" (page 400), Deiser: "Reelle Zahlen" (page 170), Goebbels/Ritter: "Mathematik verstehen und anwenden" (page 141), Knabner/Barth: "Lineare Algebra" (page 427), Hirn/Weis: "Analysis - Grundlagen und Exkurse" (page 329), Knabner/Reuter/Schulz: "Mit Mathe richtig anfangen" (page 350), and so on.

Comment: You are right, there are different definitions of "echt komplex" in use. I would prefer the above definition, but if you prefer the other one, then there is at least an easy answer. There is no English word in use except saying that $z$ is non-real. So the theorem "Jede quadratische Gleichung hat entweder zwei reelle oder zwei echt komplexe Lösungen" translates as "Every quadratic equation either has two real solutions, or two complex non-real ones".

Answer (score 0):

"Echt" has passed from German to English, meaning "typical" or "authentic" in both languages. So complex numbers with both parts nonzero are considered the "typical" case in the context where "echt komplex" is used in German.